# Retrieve taxonomy terms with EntityFieldQuery for a given parent term

Tags: 7, entities, taxonomy-terms

I am retrieving a tid of a taxonomy term by using `EntityFieldQuery`. However, I need to cross-link the taxonomy_term_hierarchy table to list those terms which have a particular parent, but I am not able to get it. In the code below

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
      ->propertyCondition('vid', $vocabulary)
      ->propertyCondition('name', $termino)
      ->propertyCondition('parent', $parent_id)
```

the last line is throwing the following (expected) error. The same code, without the last property condition, works correctly. How can I achieve the result?

The returned error is:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'taxonomy_term_data.parent' in 'where clause'

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested in the answer for Drupal 8, the condition would look like: `$query->condition('parent.target_id', $parent_id);` or if you want to query entities referencing taxonomy terms by a given parent id `$query->condition('field_term_reference.entity.parent.target_id', $parent_id);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using only the `EntityFieldQuery` class, you cannot because the information about the taxonomy hierarchy is not contained in the database table used for the entity data, but in the taxonomy_term_hierarchy table.

You would need to first get all the taxonomy term IDs having `$parent_id` as parent, from that table, and then use the `EntityFieldQuery` class for the other part of the query. Truly, the `EntityFieldQuery` class is excessive, in this case, since its purpose is to make a query involving the values of field attached to an entity. It also slower than a normal query done with `db_select()`, and you would not get any benefit, in this case.

Comment: I had convinced myself that EntityFieldQuery was more abstract than db_select, avoiding potential problems when changing field names or the like. For your reply and other info it seems very limitated, and in Drupal 8 this limitation may change. I will use a simple `db_query` as you suggest.